# Handling multiplayer collision

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I'm writing a simple multiplayer game in javascript using socket.io with collisions. The problem appears when I want to proceed a collision locally and then share its result with other players. The collision function obviously affects not only the local player, but also the others. Here is the code:

```
        for(const i of Object.keys(cubePositions)){
            for(const j of Object.keys(cubePositions)){
                if(i != j){
                    collision(cubePositions[i], cubePositions[j]);
                    collided = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried a naive way of sending these two new positions to other players every loop step and letting them update them locally, but of course it didn't do the job.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is, but usually the game mechanics are handled by a server, and the clients merely reflect the current game state.